# Perform operation on floats in list value that contains both floats and strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Python 3 in which all key-value pairs have the following structure:

```
my_dict = {'Jerry': [0.4, 'Queens', 0.6, 'Knicks']}
```

This means that the value is always a list with float, string, float, string.

I need to modify the values so that the two floats are averaged, and that the new dictionary looks as follows:

```
new_dict = {'Jerry': [0.5, 'Queens', 'Knicks]}
```

I have tried a `for` loop that selects the floats from the value list based on their indexes, but Python doesn't let me index through it.

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    average = sum(v[0], v[1])/2
    my_dict[k] = [average, v[1], v[3]]
```

This returns

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

How could I select the floats to work out the average?

Comment: Don't reassign to a dictionary you are currently looping over - funny things can happen. Instead create a new dictionary. e.g. `my_dict = {k: [(v[0]+v[2])/2, v[1], v[3]] for k, v in my_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass an `iterable` to the `sum()` function, so make the values `v[0]` and `v[1]` to a list by adding a `[` and `]`

### With minimal modification to your code

```
my_dict = {'Jerry': [0.4, 'Queens', 0.6, 'Knicks']}

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    average = sum([v[0], v[2]])/2
    my_dict[k] = [average, v[1], v[3]]

print(my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Jerry': [0.5, 'Queens', 'Knicks']}
```

### Or a shorter solution

```
my_dict = {'Jerry': [0.4, 'Queens', 0.6, 'Knicks'], 'Berry': [0.5, 'Queens', 0.1, 'Knicks']}

my_dict = {k:[(v[0]+v[2])/2, v[1], v[3]] for k,v in my_dict.items()}

print(my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Jerry': [0.5, 'Queens', 'Knicks'], 'Berry': [0.3, 'Queens', 'Knicks']}
```

Comment: "You need to pass an iterable to the sum() function, so make the values v[0] and v[1] to a list by adding a [ and ]" This is very valuable information and definitely what I was missing. This helped me understand more how sum() works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the `key`, `value` pairs, and create a temporary list to store numeric and string data, and iterate each value list and append to `numbers`/`strings` lists based on `type`, finally find the `average` and add it to the resulting dictionary.

```py
my_dict = {'Jerry': [0.4, 'Queens', 0.6, 'Knicks']}
result = {}

for key,value in my_dict.items():
    numbers = []
    strings =[]
    for item in value:
        if type(item) is float:
            numbers.append(item)
        else:
            strings.append(item)
    result[key] = [sum(numbers)/len(numbers)] + strings
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
{'Jerry': [0.5, 'Queens', 'Knicks']}
```

**PS**: This solution will work even if you have more or less number of items in the value list of the given dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument for [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is supposed to take an iterable (e.g., a list).

You can either use `average = sum([v[0], v[2]])/2` as suggested by [@abhi-j](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15347805/abhi-j) or just `average = (v[0]+v[2])/2`.